# date validation in javascript

Tags: validation, date

I have two text boxes, one is "**From Date**" and "**To Date**". user will enter the date in the format of "**mm/dd/yyyy**". Here the "**To Date**" is always Greater than "From Date". if not, i will alert the user "**Not valide, To date is always greater than From Date**".

Ex: From Date: 06/05/2011
    To Date:   05/08/2011

The above statement is wrong.

```
       Please give your answer.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693298/js-check-for-valid-date-format/28777878#28777878

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll probably want to use [<input type="date">](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-date), which does some validation on browsers that support it, and shows as a regular input box on browsers that don't.

For actually validating that one date is before the other, you can use a [JavaScript Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```
var fromDate = new Date(from.value);
if (isNaN(fromDate.getTime())
  alert("Invalid From Date");
var toDate = new Date(end.value);
if (isNaN(toDate.getTime())
  alert("Invalid To Date");
if (toDate < fromDate)
  alert("Not valid, To date is always greater than From Date");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's one way to do it.  Another might be to ask if the user wishes to reverse the two.